# How to update database with server-side information without reloading the page

Tags: php

I'm developing a like/dislike system using php and MySQL, but I have a problem. When I add a like, let's say, I do it by adding a row to the likes table, that contains the post id and the user id. The user id is stored in a $_SESSION, and I can't just pass it to the html and make a AJAX request to run some php code and add the like, because this way it's too easy to simply change the user id.

So basicaly I don't want to reload the page to first get the $_SESSION value but I don't now how to get it's value after the page has loaded. I don't know if this is doable with php only, if not, what language should I use

Comment: Add authentication/password along with user id and then it doesn't matter if someone tries to change user id on client side

Comment: If the user id is stored in the session, then the user id is not visible to the client side. Ajax requests calling another php script will run in the same session - unless the target php is on a different domain.

Comment: @Shadow I was trying to use the $_SESSION value with the AJAX request and I couldn't get it, but I was probalby doing something wrong. I'm going to try it again, thank you.

Comment: To get the session ($_SESSION), don't forget to start your ajax .php file with `session_start()`

Comment: If you are struggling to make your php code called by an ajax script to run in the same session as the other php scripts, then you could ask that as a question along with your php and ajax scripts.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using send ajax request for saving the like or dislike value. after saving the like/dislike value. you have to return a new like value count. in PHP simply echo the value that will automatically come to your ajax success if not simply return the new like/dislike info, encode with JSON and return the value.
get these values in the success function and target the like and dislike button or div and change the new value with an ajax response.

if you want to code answer please share your code here so it's better understood by everyone